# Is absolute convergence the same as unconditional convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The Riemann Series Theorem states that a conditionally convergent series, upon permutation, can be made to converge to any value, or diverge.

I want to know when we can guarantee that a series converges to the same value, no matter whether the terms are permuted or not, i.e. when is a series *unconditionally* convergent?  Is unconditionally convergent equivalent to absolutely convergent?  If so, under what restrictions (e.g. only sums of elements of ordered fields, or on elements of sets isomorphic of $\Bbb C$, etc)?

Comment: Wikipedia has a [succinct explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconditional_convergence#Alternative_definition)

Comment: That article is a little too succinct.  For instance it doesn't give an obvious (at least not obvious to me) way of proving Przemyslaw's claim.

Comment: ....Fair enough

Comment: Oh but the pdf "A Basis Theory Primer" linked at the bottom is a wealth of information.  Thanks @Omnomnomnom.  I didn't even realize that "unconditional convergence" was the name for what I was talking about, I thought I had made it up. :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally they are not equivalent, but in finite dimension they are the same.